# Why SIGTERM event handler wasn't called in my code example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sigint, sigterm

Windows 10 x64
Node v12.19.0

Why wasn't called my handler of `SIGTERM` event after first opening `http://localhost:3000/` in a browser? Application is terminated without executiong my handler (I don't see its console output).

```
// node v12.19.0
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=> {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.end("Hello, World!");
    setTimeout(() => { process.kill(process.pid, "SIGTERM"); } , 2000);
});

process.on("SIGTERM", () => { // Why it will not be executed?
    process.statusCode = 1;
    console.log("SIGTERM");
    server.close(() => {
        console.log("Process terminated.");
    });
});

server.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server works on http://localhost:3000/");  
});
```

My console output (PowerShell):

```
PS C:\tmp_src> node index.js
Server works on http://localhost:3000/
PS C:\tmp_src>
```

Comment: As per https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events: "'SIGTERM' is not supported on Windows, it can be listened on."

Comment: @msbit thank you. What event I mast to listen instead of SIGTERM on Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that there is no such event under Windows; from the same link: "Windows does not support signals so has no equivalent to termination by signal, but Node.js offers some emulation with process.kill(), and subprocess.kill():"

Comment: @msbit thank you. Then I will use it in the linux-docker container with node.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, `process.on('SIGINT',cb)` works for me, to catch interrupts like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a shell, or stop button commands in an IDE.

It also works well in production on Linux, particularly for `pm2 restart` and similar commands.

Comment: You are right: `SIGINT` works for `CTRL` + `C`. But it doesn't work if I open the URL.